# Segmentation fault caused by pthread_kill

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, segmentation-fault, posix

GDB tells me that `pthread_kill` is causing a segmentation fault in my program. Basically I'm using `pthread_kill` to check if a thread is alive or not given its ID.

I've been searching the web and found that it might be that `pthread_kill` is causing segmentation fault when TID is invalid. Yes, I have been testing my program using "invalid"(contrived by me) TIDs of type `int`. Could that be the real cause?

Comment: What "invalid" values are you using?

Comment: Since pthread_t is an opaque type, using an integer (like 1001) could theoretically cause problems and a subsequent crash. Do you get any warnings compiling with -Wall?

Comment: Have you run the program under valgrind?

Comment: ignore my previous comment, I was looking at the old linuxthreads implementation :)

Comment: @DanFego Unfortunately no warnings at all :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`pthread_t` is not a thread ID, or a numeric index. It is an opaque type. Making up values can result in a crash.

On Linux NPTL, pthread_t is used as a pointer:

```
int
__pthread_kill (threadid, signo)
     pthread_t threadid;
     int signo;
{
  struct pthread *pd = (struct pthread *) threadid;
```

It should be fairly clear where things are going wrong already :) Note that this pointerness is also an implementation detail - the older Linuxthreads implementation used numeric indices into a table, and there you could indeed make up TIDs and not expect things to crash.

You need to be tracking thread life and death yourself. A `pthread_t` is valid until you call `pthread_join` on it successfully. If you want to test whether a *valid* `pthread_t` is alive, call `pthread_tryjoin_np` on it; if it returns `EBUSY`, the thread is alive. If the function succeeds, *the `pthread_t` is no longer valid*; you must not re-use it at this point - so you must make a note somewhere that that thread is dead now, and there's no need to check it anymore!

You could, of course, implement your own tracking system - create a table somewhere of liveness, a system for handing out TIDs, and passing them into newly created threads. Have each thread mark itself as dead prior to exiting (perhaps using `pthread_cleanup_push` so you handle thread cancellation and `pthread_exit`), and detach the thread so you don't need to join it (using `pthread_detach`). Now you have explicit control of your thread-death reporting.

Comment: The man page for [pthread_kill](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_kill.3.html) says you can use `pthread_kill(t, 0)` to 'check for existence of t', which implies being able to make the call with invalid pthread_t values.  Is the man page incorrect?

Comment: @Brandon see http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4509 and http://udrepper.livejournal.com/16844.html. dreppers argument sems pretty intellectually lazy, but it would appear that there is no intention of supporting pthread_kill on invalid TIDs in glibc, so the approach of using pthread_kill to test for the existence of the thread is no worky

Comment: POSIX is very clear that use of a `pthread_t` after its lifetime is UB, and POSIX 2008 (either original or first TC, I forget) clarified this further by removing the bogus "may fail" errors. Further, future issues of POSIX intend to ban `ESRCH` as an error for threads which have exited but not been joined.

Answer (score 2):

To get around this limitation in my code, I set the TID to zero when the code is not running

```
memset(&thread, '\0', sizeof(pthread_t));
```

...
and check it for null before calling pthread_kill

```
//this code will run if thread is not valid
if (!thread || ESRCH == pthread_kill(thread, 0)) {
    //do stuff and create the thread
}
```